# how to validate date?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a Texbox which is created for entering the date. I have used a RegularExpressionValidator for the format `dd-mm-yyyy`. It works properly.

```
<asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="RegularExpressionValidator1" runat="server" 
    ControlToValidate="tb_date" ErrorMessage="dd-mm-yyyy" 
    ValidationExpression="\d{1,2}-\d{1,2}-\d{4}">
</asp:RegularExpressionValidator>
```

But I also need to evaluate that the entered date shouldn't be less than today's date. How can I implement it? Please help ...

Comment: You can use custom validator for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

2 you,
because you were using RegularExpressionValidator to validate a part of inputed date, so i will introduce you an solution to validate inputed date with today by using validate control
- first on designer

```
<asp:Calendar ID="EndDate" runat="server" OnSelectionChanged="EndDate_OnSelectionChanged">
</asp:Calendar>
<asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txtEndDate"></asp:TextBox>
<asp:CompareValidator runat="server" ID="CompareEndTodayValidator" ErrorMessage="The date must be less than today"
    ControlToValidate="txtEndDate" Type="Date" Operator="LessThan"></asp:CompareValidator>
```

- on code behind:

protected void EndDate_OnSelectionChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            txtEndDate.Text = EndDate.SelectedDate.ToShortDateString();
        }

- on pageload of codebehind

  CompareEndTodayValidator.ValueToCompare = DateTime.Now.ToShortDateString();

i hope it can help you :)

Answer (score 2):

You can create a [`CustomValidator`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.customvalidator.aspx) that will parse the value to a `DateTime`

```
DateTime.ParseExact(str, "dd-mm-yyyy")
```

Or you can create a validation on javascript that will convert the value to a date and compare to now

Answer (score 1):

You need to check with following condition:

```
if(Datetime.parse(txtdate.Text)<DateTime.Now)
{
    Responce.Write("<head><script type='text/javascript'>alert('Date is greater than today's date');</script></head>");
}
```

Comment: then how can i written the code for displaying error message ? <asp:CustomValidator ID="CustomValidator1" runat="server" 
ControlToValidate="tb_date" ErrorMessage="*" onservervalidate="DateValidate"></asp:CustomValidator>

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
        if (DateTime.Now.Date > givenDate.Date)
        {
            //Show error message
        }
```

Comment: what is givenDate.Date? [which Control?]

Comment: the `givenDate` is the date that was parsed, the question was `need to evaluate that the entered date shouldn't be less than today's date`

Comment: answer's approach is right, but only confusion was that because user has clearly mentioned TextBox for date.

Answer (score 1):

I will vote for always TryParseExact

```
if (DateTime.TryParseExact(txtdate.Text, format, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture,     DateTimeStyles.None, out userDob))
{
    if (userDob < DateTime.Now )
    //TODO: Message will displayed
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Hey Try this one.

```
        string dateString = finalDate; // <-- Valid
        string format = "dd/MM/yyyy";
        DateTime dateTime;
        if (!DateTime.TryParseExact(dateString, format, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture,
            DateTimeStyles.None, out dateTime))
        {
            message = "Date is not correct format.it should be in dd/mm/yyyy";
        }
```

Hope It helps you.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use additionally Range Validator. Just use two (Regex and Range) validators to one control. Here you can find discussion about that: http://forums.asp.net/t/1287771.aspx

Please also remember that you can add some validation in logic. Please imagine that for example you have to check before upload that file is  less than 10MB pdf document. So there is no impelmented control for that and you have to implement your own validation in logic side. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Create an object of `Timespan` and simply subtract the inout date from current date. check this code : `TimeSpan ts = d1.Subtract(d2);`
and this thread : [Date Difference in C#](http://languagelassi.blogspot.in/2012/05/date-difference-in-c.html)

Answer (score 0):

Use your custom validator could be a better option. You should do it for the best fit.